# Can a drag select on a NSTextView (with a NSTextTable) only select one column?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsattributedstring, nstextview

How do I make a drag select on a NSTextView with an NSAttributedString that contains a 2 column NSTextTable, only select the text in the 1st column?

i.e.

```
    [hi | 10:00 AM]
    [hello | 10:01 AM]
    [what are you doing? | 10:02 AM]
    [nothing, you? | 10:03 AM]
```

When you click the drag, the times are not selected, only the conversation.  You can see skype do this here:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2510380/skype.mov

**Update**:

I think skype is using a WebView and the CSS:

```
-webkit-user-select: none
```

and then

```
-webkit-user-select: text
```

for the parts that are selectable.

Comment: It's not possible to select the content of multiple text views located in different views. How did you get this behaviour working? Maybe then I can help you.

Comment: This is just a thought. But wouldn't it be possible to take your NSTextField data and show that as a PDF? That way the user could select everything.

Comment: @NSAddict it's not multiple text views.  Just 1 big NSAttributedString inside 1 NSTextView.

Comment: @Mikael hmmm interesting PDF idea!  But I'm really trying to capture the same thing skype did in the video above where the names, images, and times are not selectable but the conversation is.  It's almost like I need a NSParagraphStyle of 'not-selectable' but there doesn't seem to be that option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know how to solve this problem using NSTextView, but I found one solution using WebView + HTML5 + canvas + javascript

Names are created as canvas objects and text is just normal text in html:

[image]

When text is selected, it looks like this:

[image]

And after copy+paste you get only conversation as result:

[image]

---

I used canvas because using "-webkit-user-select: none;" in div, text will be copied if you select text around that div. And javascript is needed to create new canvas dynamically.

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 20;
canvas.setAttribute("style", "-webkit-user-select: none;");

var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
context.font="15px Arial";
context.fillText(text,0,20);
```

Calling javascript function from objective-c:

```
[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"myFunction()"];
```

So this solution is very easy to implement.

Comment: thanks, I was trying to avoid HTML/Javascript if I can.  But I like your idea.  I might end up doing this.  Any way to tell if skype is using a webview?  I get the felling it's just a NSTextView.

Answer (score 0):

You may create multiple tables with one column each and arrange them to give a feel of one single table.

This will allow selection of single column in a table.

Comment: hmmm but it's more than just that.  In the video above the name, images, and timestamp are not selectable but the conversation is.  Is there anyway to say in an attributed string, these sections are not selectable?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that may help you in the right direction, it will only allow selection of text in between your two delimeters '[' and '|'.  The only thing is once a line is partially selected it will select the whole line. This can be changed if needed by using the overlap value.  I have not fully tested it as I have yet to create the .xib to match your set up.

```
- (NSArray *)textView:(NSTextView *)aTextView willChangeSelectionFromCharacterRanges:(NSArray *)oldSelectedCharRanges toCharacterRanges:(NSArray *)newSelectedCharRanges
{
    NSMutableArray *newRanges = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString *fullText = aTextView.string;
    //Regex to find text between [ and |, the only text we should highlight
    NSString *pattern = @"\[(.*?)\|";
    NSRegularExpression *expression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:nil];

    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0,[fullText length]);
    [expression enumerateMatchesInString:fullText options:0 range:range usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop)
        {
        NSRange matchedRange = [result rangeAtIndex:1];
        //Loop through all ranges to see if they contain any allowable text
        for (int i=0; i<newSelectedCharRanges.count; i++)
        {
            NSRange rangeToCheck = [[newSelectedCharRanges objectAtIndex:i] rangeValue];
            NSRange overlap = NSIntersectionRange(rangeToCheck, matchedRange);
            if (overlap.length > 0)
            {
                //If text has been partially selected, select whole allowable range
                [newRanges addObject:[NSValue valueWithRange:matchedRange]];
            }
        }
    }];
    return newRanges;
}
```

Comment: hmmm i think the problem with this approach is when you click the drag the selection turns blue and willChangeSelectionFromCharacterRanges is only called AFTER you let go of the mouse button.  If you watch the video above the blue selection highlight is correct while dragging.  I'm beginning to think this is a WebView with HTML/CSS and not a TextView.